# How to draw a shape in Android

Tags: android, drawing

I am learning Android and trying to draw different shapes on the Canvas. At the moment I am stuck with an oval with different angles:

[image]

I've tried to use `path.addRoundRect()` method (the one which takes array of radiuses), but couldn't figure out what values should I pass there in order to achieve such shape. I've also tried using `path.lineTo()`, but could not achieve such result (it was kind of similar, but still not what I needed). What would be a good solution to accomplish this?

**Edit 1** :What I have tried is following:

```
Path path= new Path();
    path.moveTo(x - radius, y - radius/ 1.5f);
    path.lineTo(x - radius/ 4, y - radius);
    path.lineTo(x, y - radius);
    path.lineTo(x + radius/ 2, y - radius);
    path.lineTo(x + radius, y - radius/ 2);
    path.lineTo(x, y + radius/ 2);
    path.lineTo(x - radius/ 2, y + radius/ 1.5f);
    path.lineTo(x - radius, y + radius/ 4);
    path.lineTo(x - radius, y - radius/ 1.5f);
    path.close();

Paint pathPaint = new Paint();
        pathPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);                    
        pathPaint.setStrokeWidth(2.5f);              
        pathPaint.setDither(true);                    
        pathPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);       
        pathPaint.setStrokeJoin(Join.ROUND); 
        pathPaint.setStrokeCap(Cap.ROUND);      
        pathPaint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(20)); 
        pathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawOval(new RectF(x - radius, y - radius+ 2, x + radius-2, y + radius- 2), pathPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(path, pathPaint);
```

X and Y are some coordinates on a display and radius is a radius of the circle (I started drawing with a circle). Its equal to 14 px.

I've also tried this way:

```
float[] radii = new float[] {
                5, 
                5,
                1,
                1,
                5,
                1,
                1,
                1,

        };
        path.addRoundRect(new RectF(x - radius, y - radius, x + radius, 

y + radius), 
                    radii, Direction.CW);
canvas.drawPath(path, pathPaint);
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/OvalShape.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the Canvas.skew() function. There is a good example at the URL below. Skew "tilts" the points being drawn. You'll get different results based on the current center of the canvas, so translate() as needed to get the results you want.

http://css3files.com/transform/

Comment: thank you for a suggestion. I am not able to verify it as I am not working on this project atm. Maybe some one else can confirm, if it is working or not.